# Can't install kernel-uek-headers for currently running kernel

Tags: linux, oracle, vmware-player, linux-kernel, vmware-tools

I have just created a VM in VMWare and installed a minimal install of Oracle Enterprise Linux 6.3.

```
# cat /etc/oracle-release
Oracle Linux Server release 6.3
```

It is running with the UEK kernel.

```
# uname -r
2.6.39-200.24.1.el6uek.x86_64
```

When I try and install VMWare Tools, I get the following error.

```
Searching for a valid kernel header path...
The path "" is not a valid path to the 2.6.39-200.24.1.el6uek.x86_64 kernel
headers.
Would you like to change it? [yes]
```

I have version 2.6.39 of the UEK installed, but the kernel-uek-headers are only 2.6.32.

```
# yum list kernel-uek
Installed Packages
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.39-200.24.1.el6uek            @anaconda-UEK2/6.3
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.39-200.29.3.el6uek            @ol6_UEK_latest

# yum list kernel-uek-headers
Installed Packages
kernel-uek-headers.x86_64           2.6.32-300.32.2.el6uek           @ol6_latest
```

And it appears that the headers for 2.6.39 aren't there.

```
# yum list kernel-uek-headers --showduplicates
Installed Packages
kernel-uek-headers.x86_64           2.6.32-300.32.2.el6uek           @ol6_latest
Available Packages
kernel-uek-headers.x86_64           2.6.32-100.28.5.el6              ol6_latest
kernel-uek-headers.x86_64           2.6.32-100.28.9.el6              ol6_latest
kernel-uek-headers.x86_64           2.6.32-100.28.11.el6             ol6_latest
kernel-uek-headers.x86_64           2.6.32-100.28.15.el6             ol6_latest
kernel-uek-headers.x86_64           2.6.32-100.28.17.el6             ol6_latest
kernel-uek-headers.x86_64           2.6.32-100.34.1.el6uek           ol6_latest
kernel-uek-headers.x86_64           2.6.32-100.35.1.el6uek           ol6_latest
kernel-uek-headers.x86_64           2.6.32-100.36.1.el6uek           ol6_latest
kernel-uek-headers.x86_64           2.6.32-100.37.1.el6uek           ol6_latest
kernel-uek-headers.x86_64           2.6.32-200.16.1.el6uek           ol6_latest
kernel-uek-headers.x86_64           2.6.32-200.19.1.el6uek           ol6_latest
kernel-uek-headers.x86_64           2.6.32-200.20.1.el6uek           ol6_latest
kernel-uek-headers.x86_64           2.6.32-200.23.1.el6uek           ol6_latest
kernel-uek-headers.x86_64           2.6.32-300.3.1.el6uek            ol6_latest
kernel-uek-headers.x86_64           2.6.32-300.4.1.el6uek            ol6_latest
kernel-uek-headers.x86_64           2.6.32-300.7.1.el6uek            ol6_latest
kernel-uek-headers.x86_64           2.6.32-300.11.1.el6uek           ol6_latest
kernel-uek-headers.x86_64           2.6.32-300.20.1.el6uek           ol6_latest
kernel-uek-headers.x86_64           2.6.32-300.21.1.el6uek           ol6_latest
kernel-uek-headers.x86_64           2.6.32-300.24.1.el6uek           ol6_latest
kernel-uek-headers.x86_64           2.6.32-300.25.1.el6uek           ol6_latest
kernel-uek-headers.x86_64           2.6.32-300.27.1.el6uek           ol6_latest
kernel-uek-headers.x86_64           2.6.32-300.29.1.el6uek           ol6_latest
kernel-uek-headers.x86_64           2.6.32-300.29.2.el6uek           ol6_latest
kernel-uek-headers.x86_64           2.6.32-300.32.1.el6uek           ol6_latest
kernel-uek-headers.x86_64           2.6.32-300.32.2.el6uek           ol6_latest
```

The kernel for 2.6.32 is there.

```
# yum list kernel-uek --showduplicates
Installed Packages
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.39-200.24.1.el6uek            @anaconda-UEK2/6.3
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.39-200.29.3.el6uek            @ol6_UEK_latest
Available Packages
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.32-100.28.5.el6               ol6_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.32-100.28.9.el6               ol6_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.32-100.28.11.el6              ol6_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.32-100.28.15.el6              ol6_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.32-100.28.17.el6              ol6_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.32-100.34.1.el6uek            ol6_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.32-100.35.1.el6uek            ol6_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.32-100.36.1.el6uek            ol6_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.32-100.37.1.el6uek            ol6_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.32-200.16.1.el6uek            ol6_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.32-200.19.1.el6uek            ol6_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.32-200.20.1.el6uek            ol6_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.32-200.23.1.el6uek            ol6_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.32-300.3.1.el6uek             ol6_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.32-300.4.1.el6uek             ol6_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.32-300.7.1.el6uek             ol6_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.32-300.11.1.el6uek            ol6_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.32-300.20.1.el6uek            ol6_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.32-300.21.1.el6uek            ol6_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.32-300.24.1.el6uek            ol6_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.32-300.25.1.el6uek            ol6_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.32-300.27.1.el6uek            ol6_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.32-300.29.1.el6uek            ol6_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.32-300.29.2.el6uek            ol6_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.32-300.32.1.el6uek            ol6_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.32-300.32.2.el6uek            ol6_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.39-100.5.1.el6uek             ol6_UEK_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.39-100.6.1.el6uek             ol6_UEK_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.39-100.7.1.el6uek             ol6_UEK_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.39-100.10.1.el6uek            ol6_UEK_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.39-200.24.1.el6uek            ol6_UEK_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.39-200.29.1.el6uek            ol6_UEK_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.39-200.29.2.el6uek            ol6_UEK_latest
kernel-uek.x86_64           2.6.39-200.29.3.el6uek            ol6_UEK_latest
```

Should I downgrade the kernel to 2.6.32 so I can install VMWare tools? Is there another way to get the kernel-uek-headers package for the 2.6.39 UEK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10245301) topic, `kernel-uek-headers` may not be needed any more.

Follow [this](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10245945) howto to install `kernel-uek-devel` package, patch the `vmware-config-tools.pl` installation script and try again.

Comment: These links are lost to time.

Answer (score 2):

Just bumped into this one myself. This command will download the correct headers:

```
yum install kernel-uek-devel-`uname -r`
```

This one returns a newer version, which is enough to throw the vmware-install.pl script a curve ball. I did my installation on VMWare Workstation 8.0.4.

```
yum kernel-uek-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the link of the preview comment: https://serverfault.com/a/423140/1045994

I think that this is the right link:
https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/vmware-tools-and-oracle-linux-howto-6363